# EmptyDataError : No columns to parse from file

Tags: python, html, pandas, parsing, flask

I'm trying to write a flask code in VSCode that reads a CSV file and displays it on the browser as a table.
This is the **.py** code:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template,request
import os
import pandas as pd

app=Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key="123"

app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER1"]="static/csv"

@app.route("/upload",methods=['GET','POST'])
def upload():
    return render_template("UploadCsv.html")

@app.route("/display",methods=["GET","POST"])
def display():
    upload_file = request.files['upload_csv']
    if upload_file.filename != '':
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER1"], upload_file.filename)
            upload_file.save(file_path)
            data=pd.read_csv(upload_file,sep=",")
            return render_template("ExcelContent.html",data=data.to_html(index=False))

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I've used Two HTML files in the code, here are those:
**UploadCsv.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload CSV File</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-5" style="margin-top:70px">
            <form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/display" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <h3 class="page-header text-primary">Upload CSV File</h3>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Browse CSV File</label>
                    <input type="file" class="form-control" name="upload_csv">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Upload CSV</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CsvContent.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSV File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Here's your uploaded CSV file :</h2>
    {{data|safe}}
</body>
</html>
```

Now when I run the .py and open my localhost and upload a csv, the above mentioned error pops up. The folder to which my csv file has to get stored when I click "submit" is working fine. The display part is where this error pops up. I don't know how to rectify that. My file is a simple CSV file (seperated by commas). This is the picture of the error message:
[image: This is the picture of the error message:]

Help me with resolving the error, Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably should pass the `filepath` to `pd.read_csv` method, as shown below:

```
def display():
    upload_file = request.files['upload_csv']
    if upload_file.filename != '':
            file_path = os.path.join(app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER1"], upload_file.filename)
            upload_file.save(file_path)
            data=pd.read_csv(file_path,sep=",")
            return render_template("ExcelContent.html",data=data.to_html(index=False))
```